# inserting data to mysql table using csv/xls file

Tags: php, mysql

I am planing to build a CMS based web application in which user can upload daily report in the format of CSV or XLS(X), my question is that,how to insert that data to mysql table ?, Thanks in advance
I am new in php programming.

Comment: You asked "how to insert that data to mysql table" => INSERT INTO table (filed1,field2) VALUES(1,2)

Comment: @jitesh Tukadiya - did u got the Answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1).Upload CSV for mysql**

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into tablename(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";

        mysqli_query($import) or die(mysqli_error());
    }
```

[Read more here](http://coyotelab.org/blog/php/upload-csv-and-insert-into-database-using-phpmysql).

**2). Uploading Exel files** 

with PHP Excel Reader :

http://rackerhacker.com/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/

Comment: i think you need to surround those array item variables in `{}`. Also you should be escaping them with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. And Lastly, you shouldnt be using `mysql_*` but `mysqli` or `PDO` :-)

Comment: surround those array item variables in {} @prodigitalson not getting you !

Comment: should be `{$data[0]}` for example...

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to insert data into MySQL DB from a file :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/myCSVFile.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
```

Check MySQL page for more options and details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Here is a good tutorial : http://www.zorrito.com/csv-vers-mysql-correspondance-des-colonnes/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a script to pull in information from a CSV file, you can link MYSQL directly to it and upload the information using the following SQL syntax.

To import an Excel file into MySQL, first export it as a CSV file. Remove the CSV headers from the generated CSV file along with empty data that Excel may have put at the end of the CSV file.

You can then import it into a MySQL table by running:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

The fields here are the actual tblUniq table fields that the data needs to sit in. The enclosed by and lines terminated by are optional and can help if you have columns enclosed with double-quotes such as Excel exports, etc.

Comment: While this is the fastest it its probably not the best way as he is new to PHP. Depending on the hosting set up and his level of control he may not be able to successfully invoke a `load infile` query. Hes better off in this case parsing the CSV. it also gives him more control an error handling options.

Comment: is yu will call him new to PHP, then wht will yu call me? :P

I just started learing PHP today afternoon

Comment: Well i only called that out because he specifically stated he was new to php in his question. And its not a matter of doing this on your local development machine, thats usually easy to get working. Its when you deploy to a hosting set up that you may not be able to `load ... infile` do to restrictions which you cannot change. Just speaking from experience :-) besides there are other benefits to actually inserting each row. I would only use the load if it was data I had prepared myself and was on hand to modify if something went wrong - but this sounds like a feature for andmin user.